# How to pow and mod giant numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pow

I'd like to put a number to some power, then multiply it with another number and lastly mod it.

Python's pow function, that takes 3 parameters can't be used for my use-case scenario, so I'm trying to find fast alternative.

Examples:

I know I can do

```
9^10%2
```

as

```
pow(9, 10, 2)
```

but I can't do

```
(8*9^10)%2
```

with the same function

I've already tried using(numbers only for reference, real numbers a lot bigger)

```py
pow(9, 10)*8 % 2 # tooks too long
pow(9, 10, 2)*8  # returns wrong answer
```

I'd like my numbers to be calculated really fast, even if they're up to 10^18. My time requirement is 2s for 20 of those numbers.

None of the above solutions didn't really work for me, either they were too slow or didn't return correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second solution contains an incorrect assumption that the following is true. Intuitively, it cannot be true because the first expression could be as large as `c*(n-1)`, but the second must be strictly less than `n`

```
((a^b)%n)*c == (c*a^b))%n
```

The correct identity from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
ab mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n.
```

We can generalize this by induction (proof is left as an exercise to the reader):

[image: \prod^m_{k=1}{x_k} \mod n = \prod^m_{k=1}{(x_k \mod n)} \mod n]

So your expression should be:

```
(pow(9, 10, 2) * (8 % 2)) % 2
# OR
(pow(9, 10, 2) * 8) % 2
```